# Powershell pipelinevariable lost/overwritten when using Sort-Object. alternative?

Tags: powershell, sorting, variables, pipeline

I'm running a series of cmdlets in a pipeline, setting a -PipeLineVariable for each, but I'm getting unexpected results due to the use of a Sort-Object cmdlet higher in the pipeline.

For example take the sample code, which is just a portion of my full code.  Get-VMhost is pulling random hosts, but my OCD is wanting an alphabetical list and only wanting to select the first 2.  As such I am adding a Sort-Object after the Get-VMhost, but that breaks the pipeline variable at the end.

```
get-vmhost -PipelineVariable VMHost | sort Name | select -first 2 | % {write-host $vmhost} 

VMHost3
VMHost3
```

Instead, I expected to see

```
VMHost1
VMHost2
```

I understand this to be a result of some cmdlets such as Sort-Object as having to aggregate all input to process and then breaking the stream.  I sort of understand this.

Without the use of ...

```
Select -First 2
```

... I will get the whole dataset and I can simply sort as my final step to sort it all.  I could just also add the select -first 2 at the end.
I'm just trying to understand the issue and why it happens and if there's an inline workaround up front.

***Edit... I have my answer, which is simply to set the pipelinevariable AT the sort statement.  Thanks @mklement0

Comment: Why not just do `$vmhost = get-vmhost` and then `$vmhost | Sort....`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, that wasn't the issue.  I was wanting an understanding of why the pipeline variable was being broken by the Sort and if there was a workaround as my intention was to keep it as a one-liner.  I'm good now though.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) *with the `Sort-Object` cmdlet* instead of `Get-VMHost` in order to have the pipeline variable reflect the *sorted* object sequence.

A simplified example:

```
3, 6, 2, 1 | Sort-Object -PipelineVariable value | Select-Object -First 2 |
  ForEach-Object { $value }
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score -1):

The code in your question is behaving as expected / designed (see below).

I'm not sure what you want achieve, but probably you want the following:

```
$myVMs = get-vmhost | sort Name | select -first 2
$myVMs | ForEach-Object { write-host $_ }
```

or, in a single pipeline:

```
get-vmhost | sort Name | select -first 2 | ForEach-Object { write-host $_ }
```

Reference: [about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters)

> PipelineVariable allows access to the most recent value passed into the next pipeline segment by the command that uses this parameter. Any command in the pipeline can access the value using the named PipelineVariable. The value is assigned to the variable when it is passed into the next pipeline segment. This makes the PipelineVariable easier to use than a specific temporary variable, which might need to be assigned in multiple locations.

> Unlike `$_` or `$PSItem`, using a PipelineVariable allows any pipeline command to access pipeline values passed (and saved) by commands other than the immediately preceding command. Pipeline commands can access the last value piped from while processing the next item passing through the pipeline. This allows a command to feed back its output to a previous command (or itself).

> **Caution**

> The PipelineVariable is scoped to the pipeline in which it is invoked. Variables outside the pipeline, which use same name, are removed before the pipeline is executed. The PipelineVariable goes out of scope when the pipeline terminates. If multiple commands within the pipeline specify the same PipelineVariable then there is only one shared variable. That variable is updated with the most recent piped output from the command that specifies the variable.

> Some blocking commands collect all the pipeline items before producing any output, for example Sort-Object or Select-Object -Last. Any PipelineVariable assigned in a command before such a blocking command always contains the final piped item from the preceding command when used in a command after the blocking command.